# Add/remove Google maps markers

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a simple React app that adds a marker when the map is clicked on. And when a marker is clicked on it should be removed.

There seems to be a bug somewhere though as clicking to add markers, and then removing some doesn't work as expeted most of the time.

Here's what I have so far.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Wrapper } from '@googlemaps/react-wrapper';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([
    { lat: 51, lng: 16 },
    { lat: 51, lng: 19 },
    { lat: 51, lng: 22 },
  ]);
  const loc = {
    lat: 51,
    lng: 16,
  };
  const mapOptions = {
    center: loc,
    zoom: 4,
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add and remove map markers</h1>
      <p>Click the map to add a marker, or click a marker to delete it.</p>
      <Wrapper apiKey="">
        <GoogleMap opt={mapOptions} markers={markers} setMarkers={setMarkers} />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

function GoogleMap(props) {
  const { opt, setMarkers, markers } = props;
  const [map, setMap] = useState();
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const listeners = markers.map((marker) => {
      const gmarker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: marker, map: map });
      const listener = gmarker.addListener('click', ({ domEvent, latLng }) => {
        //const newMarkers = markers.filter((m) => m !== marker);
        //setMarkers(newMarkers);
        gmarker.setMap(null);
      });
      return listener;
    });

    return () => {
      listeners.forEach((listener) => {
        listener.remove();
      });
    };
  }, [map, markers, setMarkers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const clickListener = map.addListener('click', (e) => {
      const markerLocation = {
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng(),
      };
      //new google.maps.Marker({ position: markerLocation, map: map });
      setMarkers([...markers, markerLocation]);
    });

    return () => {
      clickListener.remove();
    };
  }, [map, markers, setMarkers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMap(new google.maps.Map(ref.current, opt));
  }, [setMap]);

  return <div ref={ref} style={{ height: '400px', width: '100%' }} />;
}
```

And here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-moz5ea?file=App.tsx,package.json) of the code running.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is the way you add and remove the `markers`.
we must remove the marker from the markers list when click on it. if not, the removed markers will appear again because we haven't filtered them out of the markers list.

```js
      const listener = gmarker.addListener('click', ({ domEvent, latLng }) => {
        gmarker.setMap(null);
        // add some line below
        setMarkers((currentMarks) =>
          currentMarks.filter(
            (item) => item.lat !== marker.lat && item.lng !== marker.lng
          )
        );
      });
```

and when clicking on the map to add a new position, we don't need to use the markers because this effect will be called when markers list changes.

must fix like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    const clickListener = map.addListener('click', (e) => {
      const markerLocation = {
        lat: e.latLng.lat(),
        lng: e.latLng.lng(),
      };
      // add some line below
      setMarkers((currentMarks) => [...currentMarks, markerLocation]);
    });

    return () => {
      clickListener.remove();
    };
  }, [map, setMarkers]);
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work.